# Suitable database for Android vocabulary game?

Tags: android, database

I am trying to make an app that allows the user to learn vocabulary through a game. My app will have predefined stacks of vocab cards (Jobs, Animals, Weather,...), and later on, the user can also download new stacks of cards online.

In my previous apps, I used SQLite like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_WORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_DEF + " TEXT NOT NULL)";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}
```

I have also read about Room which can support LiveData. Which database should I use if I want both pre-defined offline databases and perhaps new online databases as well? Should I use both SQLite and an online database? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Sqlite or Room can be used to cache local data from an online database, as far as which one to use is too broad, as almost any could be made to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Room is a wrapper (abstraction layer) around SQLite they are the same database.

That is you can open and access a database used by Room in any tool that can open an SQLite Database (SQLite Version permitting). However, the reverse is not as easy, the tables, if used by Room must have near exact table defnitions (Entities).

- *For example Room only supports column types of INTEGER, TEXT, REAL and BLOB, that would suit your table, but if the table say had a column defined as `added DATETIME` then that column would have to be converted for use by room (probably to either INTEGER or TEXT).*

LiveData basically observes data changes made allows the data to update to the App components that use the data. It is not a server implementation of Room that makes a database created for use by Room available online.

If you want an online database then Firebase may be an option thatt is relatively easy to incorporate on Android.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I will have a look at Firebase :D